# Flow ignore doesn't work while trying to ignore a node module

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, yarnpkg

I'm using Flow with React for the first time and I'm having problems trying to get Flow to ignore specific node modules (Styled Components for example). I have installed flow typed too, have tried a lot of different ways to get flow to ignore those modules but it keeps reporting the same errors on the modules im trying to ignore. My .flowconfig is pretty basic:

```
[ignore]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/styled-components/*
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/axios/*

[include]

[libs]

[options]
```

The flow version is 0.79.0. and its installed locally since I was having server errors with the global installation.

Comment: What error do you get ?